# Use checkbox to change the background color of a range of cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to have a checkbox change the background color of a range of cells using conditional formatting custom formula `=$N123=True`.  With the range defined in conditional formatting only the first cell changes color when the checkbox is checked.  Why would only one cell be effected?

Comment: What is the range where the conditional formatting was applied? Also add a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to lock the row number otherwise, it will look for next row and the next row have not the given criteria (`TRUE`)

**custom formula:** **`=COUNTIF($A$1, "=TRUE")`**

[image]